# T-SQL and OPENJSON tell the difference between null value and missing value?

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to find a way to do an update statement that uses a OPENJSON to update the values. My main challenge in my simple example below is that if Category is explicitly supplied in the JSON as "null" then I want to update the employee, but if the Category value is entirely missing then I want to leave the Category value as it is for that employee.

I've tried a few approaches but now I wonder if it's not possible?
My simple example only has a small number of fields but in reality my Employee table has over 100 fields.

In the example below I am hoping to update Sue Walker's Category to NULL and Tom Jones' Category should not be updated because it is missing from the JSON.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[{"ID": 1,"FullName": "Joe Brown","Category": "Sales"},{"ID": 2,"FullName": "Sue Walker","Category": null},{"ID": 3,"FullName": "Tom Jones"}]';

DECLARE @employees TABLE (ID Int, FullName VarChar(50), Category VarChar(50))
INSERT INTO @employees (ID, FullName, Category)
VALUES (1,'Joe Brown','Sales')
,(2,'Sue Walker','Sales')
,(3,'Tom Jones','Sales')

UPDATE E SET
    E.FullName = J.FullName
    ,E.Category = ISNULL(J.Category,E.Category)
FROM @employees E
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH (
        ID INT,
        FullName NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.FullName', -- Parse "FullName" property
        Category NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Category' -- Parse "FullName" property
    )) J ON J.ID = E.ID
;

SELECT * FROM @employees
```

Comment: It seems like the only way to inspect if a property exists is to use `strict` mode. Which generates an error. So it seems like you'd need to go through each element, inspect using `strict` and catch the error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#PATHMODE

Comment: No sure if this would be feasible in your situation but you could add a replace at the start of the script just after you get the @jasn populated, something like. `SET @json = replace(@json, ': null', ': "[blank]"')` then just check for the field being the string `[blank]`

Comment: That is a pretty good suggestion @alan although might have some issues with data types between strings and numbers?